# How to read JSON data from view

Tags: javascript, json, html, model-view-controller, view

How can i read more than one JSON value from my view?

i have a JSON file that is structured like:

```
{
"Cat": {
    "items": [
        {
         "posa": "a",
         "posb": "b",
         "posc": "c",
         "posd": "d",
         "pose": "e",
         "posf": "f"
        }
   ]
  },
"Dog": {
   "items" : [
       {
        "posa": "1",
        "posb": "2",
        "pos": "3",
        "posd": "4",
        "pose": "5",
        "posf": "6""
       }
    ]
}
```

}

how can i make a single call to this?

e.g if i have

```
{
    "cat": {
        "items": [
            {
                "pos": "37.622882;55.755202;0",     
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

i can call this by doing the following in my view.

```
position="{pos}"
```

what if i want to call all 6 positions. should i do something like:

```
position = "{posa,posb.posc,posd,pose,posf}"?
```

how can i get all these 6 values?

Comment: What framework are you using that takes notation like that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Object.keys() method here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys and you could use it like this:

```
var cats =  { ...Your posted data structure... },
    positions = Object.keys(cats.items[index]),
    position = '{' + positions.join(',') + '}';
```

Comment: Hello. Please look at my updated code in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
  "Cat": {
    "items": [{
      "posa": "a",
      "posb": "b",
      "posc": "c",
      "posd": "d",
      "pose": "e",
      "posf": "f"
    }, {
      "posa": "1",
      "posb": "2",
      "posc": "3",
      "posd": "4",
      "pose": "5",
      "posf": "6"

    }]
  },
  "Dog": {
    "items": [{
      "posa": "a",
      "posb": "b",
      "posc": "c",
      "posd": "d",
      "pose": "e",
      "posf": "f"
    }, {
      "posa": "1",
      "posb": "2",
      "posc": "3",
      "posd": "4",
      "pose": "5",
      "posf": "6"

    }]
  }
}

for (var k in obj) {
  obj[k].itemStrs = $.map(obj[k].items, function(item) {
    return ($.map(item, function(v) {
      return v;
    })).join()
  })
}


console.log(obj);
/*


{
  "Cat": {
    "items": [{
      "posa": "a",
      "posb": "b",
      "posc": "c",
      "posd": "d",
      "pose": "e",
      "posf": "f"
    }, {
      "posa": "1",
      "posb": "2",
      "posc": "3",
      "posd": "4",
      "pose": "5",
      "posf": "6"
    }],
    "itemStrs": ["a,b,c,d,e,f", "1,2,3,4,5,6"]
  }
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: please refer to the code i edited in my question. i forgot there are 2 arrays ad 2 objects